# facebook graph api privacy parameters when posting to a timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy, facebook-timeline

Does anyone know where its possible to find the new format of privacy parameters when posting to a timeline?

On [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/), they say some parameters are deprecated and to use the new format, but where is the new format?

Considering in the middle of the page, there is a table of privacy parameters, and the same for deprecated (except "friends"). unclear.

Answer (score 1):

That document has two tables, one is listed under the heading:

> **Deprecated Param Format**: Listed below is a description of the deprecated fields that Privacy Param used to support.

The parameters in that table may work in the short term but are deprecated

Further up the page, there's another table, listed under the heading

> **The privacy parameter contains the following fields:**

Those are the ones to use.
The two sets of parameters are broadly similar, but have differences, you should use only the first table, not the table marked 'Deprecated'

Comment: thanks, so basically they mean that the name, such as, "value", "allow", "deny" is still the same, but what you pass to it is now different ?

Comment: yep, use the examples at the top of the document, not those in the deprecated table